# I suspect that the MLE of the scale parameter in scale families of distributions is scale equivariant. Any derivative-free proof?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, scale-parameter

Suppose $f(x)=c^{-1}f_0(x/c)$, $c,x>0$. Then the MLE $\hat c_n(X_1,...,X_n)$, satisfies$$\hat c_n(aX_1,...,aX_n)=a\hat c_n(X_1,...,X_n),$$ for all $a>0.$

Comment: Have you tried writing both likelihood functions?